# JQuery date picker function isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i'm using this jquery date picker function, it works fine if i remove "year range:1930" from it, but doesn't work if i include year range. i dont know how to deal with this problem. help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('input[name="dob1"]').datepicker({
        "dateFormat": "mm/dd/yy",
            "firstDay": "1",
            "changeMonth": true,
            "changeYear": true,
            "yearRange": "1930"
    }).datepicker('option', 'onSelect', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('watermark');
    });
```

Comment: Try `"yearRange": "1930:"` or `"yearRange": "1930:+0"` which specifies the upper bound as the current year

Comment: so you just want it to have the year 1930?

Comment: @karthikr: thanks man, both "yearRange": "1930:" or "yearRange": "1930:+0" are working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your "yearRange": "1930" to "yearRange": "1930:+0"

or if you want it to start at 1930 and go forever set it to "1930:9999"

Answer (score 1):

The documentation (http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange) states:

The range of years displayed in the year drop-down: either relative to today's year (`"-nn:+nn"`), relative to the currently selected year (`"c-nn:c+nn"`), absolute (`"nnnn:nnnn"`), or combinations of these formats (`"nnnn:-nn"`).

Note that this option only affects what appears in the drop-down, to restrict which dates may be selected use the [`minDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)  and/or [`maxDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) options.

Change:

```
"yearRange": "1930"
```

To:

```
"yearRange": "1930:1930"
```